# Proof : If $\{a_n\}$ is converge then $\{|a_n|\}$ converge

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, proof-verification, proof-writing

Proof : If $\{a_n\}$ is converge then $\{|a_n|\}$ converge.

My proof :

We know that $\{a_n\}$ converge therefore :

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = L$$

All $\epsilon>0$ exist $N \in \mathbb{N}$ so for all $ n \geq N \implies |a_n-L|<\epsilon$

1. **Case $L=0$**

All $\epsilon>0$ exist $N \in \mathbb{N}$ so for all $ n \geq N \implies |a_n-0| = |a_n| =||a_n|-0|<\epsilon$

2. **Case $L>0$**

All $\epsilon>0$ exist $N \in \mathbb{N}$ so for all $ n \geq N \implies |a_n-L|<\epsilon$

exists $n \geq N \implies a_n>0$ therefore $|a_n|=a_n \implies \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = |a_n| = L$

3. **Case $L<0$**

All $\epsilon>0$ exist $N \in \mathbb{N}$ so for all $ n \geq N \implies |a_n-L|<\epsilon$

exists $n \geq N \implies a_n<0$ therefore $|a_n|=-a_n \implies \lim_{n \to \infty} |a_n| = -L(>0)$

I'd like to hear feedback for this proof, Is this proof is rigorous?

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Yes, good job! If you want to explain one thing more carefully: in case 2, say why there exists an $N$ such that $a_n>0$ for $n\ge N$ (hint: take $\epsilon=L$), and similarly in case 3.

Comment: There's a shorter proof that depends upon the following fact (which you may or may not know yet): if $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = L$, and $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=L$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(a_n) = f(L)$. The statement follows using $f(x)=|x|$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**hint**: $||a_n|-|L| | \leq |a_n-L|$

Answer (score 1):

because $\{a_n\}$ converges to $L$: given $\epsilon>0$ there is a natural $N$ so that $|L-a_n|<\epsilon$ for all $n\geq N$

$|L-a_n|<|L|-|a_n|=||L|-|a_n||$. This should prove $\{|a_n\}$ converges to $|L|$